# Не работает менеджер программ на Mint 11 Katya

Tags: установка, linux-mint, linux

Здравствуйте.

Недавно столкнулся с проблемой, менеджер программ не устанавливает приложения, как в графической оболочке, так и через терминал, скорее всего что-то с репозиториями, что конкретно не могу ответить, т.к. чайник. xD

http://pastebin.com/Vy122U2S   //результат кманды apt-get update
http://pastebin.com/bSAV81Ri  //результат команды apt-config dump

И да, в файле "`etc/apt/apt.conf`" была одна строчка, в одном линукс-чате чел скинул мне нужные строки, после этого ничего не изменилось. Пробовал настроить зеркала репозиториев, в "Источниках приложений", тоже не помогло. И ничего глобального не менял в настройках системы, как всё рухнуло.

Вообщем, жду ваших предложений :)))

Comment: А сеть-то работает? Никакой прокси для apt не указан? Похоже, что он не видит репозитории.

Comment: Сеть работает, прокси не указывал.

Comment: Нужен вывод    # cat /etc/apt/sources.list | egrep -v "^#|^$"и может ещё если есть:    # cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/* | egrep -v "^#|^$"

Comment: Попробуй sources.list привести к такому виду:    deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ katya main upstream    deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted universe multiverse    deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted universe multiverse    deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security main restricted universe     multiverse    deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ natty partner    deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main    deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ natty free non-free    deb http://www.mendeley.com/repositories/xUbuntu_11.04 

Comment: Сделал - не помогло. E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.Содержание sources.list как у тебя в сообщении. А файл sources.list.d не имеется...

Answer (score 1):

1. sudo apt-get clean
2. пропишите в /etc/resolv.conf валидные DNS-сервера
3. sudo apt-get update